# IPhone UIView - How should a UIViewController handle sizing of a UIView when its size is unknown in advance?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, resize

(IPhone newbie question)

I've subclassed a *UIViewController* and a *UIView*, and created a *InitWithFrame* for the view. My custom controller uses this to initialize its view, by frame, in its *loadView* function.

I plan to use the controller and view in my code at different places. At times under a navigation controller, toolbar, both, neither etc. This means that the code creating the view in *loadView* of the controller, should ideally know in what size to create the view.

How do I avoid hard coding these sizes for the different cases? Is there a way to build the surrounding controllers (navigation bar, etc.), then figure out the size of the viewable frame, and somehow only then create my controller and initialize my custom view using this frame size?

If my design is incorrect, any tip could be of great assistance... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the initial vew size you might be interested in [[UIScreen applicationFrame]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html). Returned rectangle accounts for the status bar and interface orientation. When your controller is used inside a navigation controller or other wrapper that changes the available screen space, I think the view gets resized automatically (through `UIViewController` magic), so there’s nothing you have to do (apart from setting a permissive `autoresizingMask`).

Comment: Thanks zoul. though, I'm not exactly sure what to do. Since the applicationFrame can't take into account the navigation controllers, etc., does that mean that my controller will inevitably draw its view initially in the wrong size? I'd prefer not to count on autoresizing magic. I don't believe in magic :)

Comment: You have to actually use: `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]` @DannyA: I can see that there would be cases where automatic resizing would be less than ideal

Comment: It seems like other UI elements know the bounds of what they are in. How does this happen? A ScrollView for example, scrolls the inner view exactly to where the visible area ends, as if it "knows" whether it's inside a tabbar or not. How does it know? [If this is known to be impossible for me to figure out, let me know and I'll approve the answer]

Comment: Views only know their geometry inside the super view (`frame`). They do not care about much else, for if they knew about the tab bar and generally about the context around them, a great mess would ensue. As for the scrolling view, that clips the content view using its own geometry. And its own geometry gets changed by somebody higher up the food chain (like the controller) when a tab bar comes on the screen.

Comment: That is exactly what I want! I want my super view (i.e. navigation controller, which is inside a tab controller) to know what size it has available to set the frame of its subview, without having to hardcode sizes or check its own superview. Somehow, when I put a scrollview, straight forward, in code, it simply "knows" its correct size without me explicitly setting its frame from its super view. Is that just behind-the-scenes resizing behavior magic?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `setFrame` method in your view and you’ll see who and in what context calls it. Usually it’s some internal part of `UIViewController`. As long as you stick to ordinary scenarios (standalone controller, controller inside navigation controller, …), it should work according to the autosizing masks without you taking special care.

Comment: Good idea! will to that. I guess this turned out to be a more complicated question than I hoped. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'm solving a similar problem: I wanted to:

- create reusable, self-contained "widget module classes" implementing a complex view built from multiple UIKit components (and other nested widget module classes!).  The higher-level customer classes of these widget classes don't care about what's a UILabel, what's a UIImageView internally within the widget, the customers only care about "displaying the score" or "showing the team logo."
- within a widget module class, lay out the UI for the widget and hookup outlets using interface builder
- for higher level customers of a widget, I wanted to be able to place the frame of the widget within the view of the customer in interface builder without having to design custom plugins to IB, etc.

These widgets are not top level controllers: so it makes no sense for them to be subclasses of UIViewController.  Then also there's the Apple advice not to have more than one VC on a visible screen at a time.    Also, there's so much advice and opinion floating around like "MVC!  MVC!   You must separate your View and your control!   MVC!" that people are so strongly discouraged from subclassing UIView or ever placing app logic within a UIView class.

But I decided to do it anyway (subclass UIView).   I've been around the block a few times (but fairly new still to the iPhone SDK/UIKit), and I'm very sensitive to design that is ugly, and that can cause problems, and I frankly don't see the problem with subclassing UIView here.   In fact there are many advantages to making your reusable widget be a subclass of UIView rather than be UIViewController-based:

- You can place a direct instance of the widget class in a customer view's interface builder layout, and the widget view's UIView frame will be properly initialized when the customer class is loaded from the xib.  This is much cleaner to me than putting a "placeholder view" in the customer, then instantiating the widget module programmatically, and setting the widget's frame to that of the placeholder, and then swapping the placeholder view for the widget's view.
- You can create a clean and simple xib file to lay out the widget's components in interface builder.  The nib file contains another UIView where all of the GUI is laid out, and then in the awakeFromNib: function of the widget, this nib view is added to the widget itself as a subview.   Any frame size adjustments can be handled here, entirely within the widget code, if any is necessary.
- The widget self-initialzes its user interface by using NSBundle's loadNibNamed:owner:options method in its own awakeFromNib method, so integration of the widget into customer classes is clean: just drop a UIView into the customer's view in IB, change the UIView's class to MyWidgetView, and in the customer's init or viewDidLoad set up any defaults in the widget's display using the widget's API that you write yourself (setScore:  setTeamImage: etc.)

It seems to me there is very, very little difference between subclassing a UIView in this way to make a reusable "widget", and using a UIViewController.  In both cases the .h file of the widget are full of members, outlets, action declarations, and special API declarations.   In both cases the .m file of the widget is full of action implementations, and special API implementation.   And the view IS separated from the control -- the view is in the xib file!

So, in summary, this is what I do for packaging up complex reusable view widgets:

- Make the widget class a subclass of UIView
- Instantiate the widget wherever you want, in other views in your app in IB directly.
- Design your widget's UI in IB.
- in the widget class's awakeFromNib: method, load the widget's UI from xib and do 
  `[self addSubview:theXibView]`
- Code the widget just like you would a UIViewController: outlets, actions, special APIs

I'd be interested in hearing about other structural systems for creating reusable widgets, and what the advantages are over this approach.

edit: forgot to mention, if the widget needs to report events to the customer class, just use a delegate protocol where the customer sets the widget's delegate to self.